# The coefficient of a root in a root system must be 0 or at least 1

Tags: coxeter-groups

Let W be a Coxeter group (not necessarily finite), and let Π and Φ be the
corresponding root basis and root system. Suppose that x ∈ Φ
+ and a ∈ Π
such that the coefficient of a in x is not zero. Prove that this coefficient must
be greater than or equal to 1. You may assume that Π is linearly independent.

Comment: In type $\mathsf{B}_2=\mathsf{C}_2$, you have a root $\beta_1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\beta_2$ where $\Pi=\{\beta_1,\beta_2\}$ and the coefficient of $\beta_2$ is $<1$. I take the geometric representation of $W$.